# Type mismatch: cannot convert from ResultSet to BigDecimal

Tags: talend

Hi I am using a `talend` job to schedule the integration of data from one database to another. My job is like:

```
tOracleInput--->tMap--->tOracleRow--->tOracleRecordSet-->tOracleOutput
```

In my `tOracleRow` there is a `big decimal` value I get using a select query:

```
Select my_value+1 my_value from MY_TABLE where id=?
```

I also propagated the query on one of my input, and using a `preparedStatement`.

On running the job I keep having this error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ResultSet to BigDecimal`, on my `tOracleRow` component.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolve the problem, I set the type of my_value of tOracleInput, tMap, tOracleRow, and tOracleRecordSet to Object. At the level of the tOracleOutput I then set it to BigDecimal. The value of my_value from the tOracleRecordSet is casted to BigDecimal before being parsed to the my_value of tOracleOutput.